# How to exclude a folder with CompareMerge?

Tags: macos, compare

On my Macbook Pro I have a purchased copy of **CompareMerge** *(by Tien Thinh Vu ~ App-Store link: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/comparemerge/id478570084?mt=12)* and want to know how to exclude a specific folder. For example the "/out" folder which does NOT need to be compared/merged when looking at 2 separate code bases of a project because it has the object files as well as other files. It just wastes time and over-populates the results when doing a compare to have it included.

**CompareMerge** is nice software and I like the way it works. However I can't figure out how to NOT include a folder.

Any ideas how this is accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You could input the folder name into the "Exclude (subfolder)" text box to exclude it.
[image: Screenshot of the exclude (subfolder) option]